# Use if else in magento homepage content

Tags: magento, if-statement, customization

I am trying to display a grid view with sale items shown on the homepage filtered by category.

I tried to put php if/else block in the homepage content in CMS section of admin, but it doesn't work. Any PHP code in the CMS is being commented automatically!

Is there any other way to filter homepage sale/featured products by category? I am using Magento 1.7.x

I have added the following code into the homepage which works:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_special" template="catalog/product/list1.phtml"}}
```

I just want to filter result of above code using categories when the user clicks on a category link on the homepage itself (not on the main menu)

Thanks
Anyone please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if/else syntax from the cms (using the customer group reference strictly as an example)...

```
{{if customer.group_id==4}} Print true {{else}} Print false {{/if}}
```

Comment: doesnt work. if/else block shows like normal text but {{block type="catalog/product_special" template="catalog/product/list1.phtml"}} shows its output