# The mystery of the CMS Page and the elusive If Statement

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to get if statement functionality in a Magento CMS Page.

[This post recommends something like the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627963/use-if-else-in-magento-homepage-content):

```
{{if customer.group_id==4}} Print true {{else}} Print false {{/if}}
```

Which is the exact kinda thing I am looking for, but this doesnt work. Is there anything similar I can use?

This is what I am trying to do:

```
{{if data.request_quote=="on"}} Yes {{else}} nope {{/if}}
```

Where `var data.request_quote` is a form variable. It keeps coming out as nope, even if `data.request_quote` is `on`.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you tried removing the "var", this isn't present in your first example.

Comment: I also believe that the variable should be a boolean, I don't think it can check against strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cant be done. This type of `if` statement will only work on boolean variables, and I can only pass string variables into this.

So my transactional emails will have to say `on` instead of `Yes`.

Very disappointing.